# Selecting theme colors in Excel *without* using RGB values?

Tags: excel, vba

I was given a sheet and I'm trying to match a very dark blue they selected.

When I click on the triangle beside the "fill icon" in the Home strip to bring up the color picker, I can see that color is the second from the bottom in the third column, the blues. It is called "Dark Blue, Text 2, 25% Darker".

I'd like to do this in VBA and use english terms for clarity. I tried various web pages that list the VBA color names, but it's not there. Is there some way to select this without resorting to numeric RGB or similar?

Comment: `?selection.interior.color` - it returns a number, coming from the values of the `R`*`G`*`B`, but it is not `RGB`.

Comment: I'm more curious if every theme color has a name or index number. Ie, can I select "Dark Blue, Text 2, 25% Darker".

Comment: Yes. Every theme color has a background color, which is within the range of `0` to `256^3-1`

Comment: No, I want to SELECT THE COLOR BY ITS NAME, something to the effect of .interior.color = ""Dark Blue, Text 2, 25% Darker"

Comment: `selection.interior.colorindex = ThisWorkbook.Styles("40 % - Akzent3").Interior.ColorIndex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to use the properties:

```
   .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5 'name of the theme
   .TintAndShade = 0.25 'darkness (1 - no dark; -1 - max dark)
```

Comment: Ahhh, let me see what I can do with that!

Comment: I think the key is GetCustomColor, but I'm not sure how to map the name I see in the picker into the right name in the index. There doesn't seem to be a way to READ the name from the selection already in a cell?

Comment: Try to record a macro... As suggested by @Vityata.

Comment: Ha! The color in question, a very dark blue, is "xlThemeColorLight2".

Comment: Actually, in retrospect, that name *does* make sense within XL. However, it also kind of destroys the original concept - if the name isn't something like "Dark Blue", there doesn't seem to be much point in using it.

Comment: You're right... But you can always make your own function to convert the names like `Dark-Blue` to the xl names like `xlThemeColorLight2`, eh eh!! If you publish it, I'll sure give you a thumbs up...

Comment: Unfortunately, while it seems you can get the color by name, you can't get the name from the color. You can get it's index number, but then you're back to square 1! Grumble, grumble, grumble...

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz - That might be part of the point, though. It's a *theme*, so it's designed to be swappable. You should be able to switch from a light theme to a dark theme, or a subdued, pastel theme to a bright, garish theme by changing the theme but keeping the color index numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Check this to see the color of the styles:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim st As Style
    Dim cnt As Long: cnt = 1

    For Each st In ThisWorkbook.Styles
        Cells(cnt, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = cnt
        Cells(cnt, 2) = cnt
        Cells(cnt, 3) = st.Name
        Cells(cnt, 4) = st.NameLocal
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next st

End Sub
```

Returning this:

[image]

If you want to use specific style for a specific selection:

```
selection.interior.colorindex = ThisWorkbook.Styles("40 % - Akzent3").Interior.ColorIndex
```

Comment: That did indeed output a nice list... but the color isn't on it! Perhaps the color is selected separately from the intensity?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz - do you mean patterns? Something like `Selection.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5`?

Comment: No, it has something to do with Theme.ThemeColorScheme.colors(x), but it doesn't seem that you can can use GetColorName with the names you see in the display.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz - have you tried to record a macro and see what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub DemoThemecolors()
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim n As Integer, m As Integer
   Dim arrNames
   Dim arrDescriptions
   Dim arrValues
   arrNames = Array("xlThemeColorAccent1", "xlThemeColorAccent2", "xlThemeColorAccent3", "xlThemeColorAccent4", "xlThemeColorAccent5", "xlThemeColorAccent6", _
                    "xlThemeColorDark1", "xlThemeColorDark2", "xlThemeColorFollowedHyperlink", "xlThemeColorHyperlink", "xlThemeColorLight1", "xlThemeColorLight2")
   arrDescriptions = Array("Accent1", "Accent2", "Accent3", "Accent4", "Accent5", "Accent6", "Dark1", "Dark2", "Followed hyperlink", "Hyperlink", "Light1", "Light2")
   arrValues = Array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 3, 12, 11, 2, 4)

   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
   Set rng = Cells(2, 7)
   rng(0, 4).Value = "TintAndShade"
   rng(1, 4).Value = 0
   For m = 1 To 9
      rng(1, m + 4).Value = 0.1 * m
   Next m
   rng(1, 1) = "ThemeColor Name"
   rng(1, 2).Value = "Value"
   rng(1, 3).Value = "Description"

   For n = 1 To 12
      rng(n + 1, 1).Value = arrNames(n)
      rng(n + 1, 2).Value = arrValues(n)
      rng(n + 1, 3).Value = arrDescriptions(n)
      rng(n + 1, 4).Interior.ThemeColor = arrValues(n)
      For m = 1 To 9
         With rng(n + 1, m + 4).Interior
            .ThemeColor = arrValues(n)
            .TintAndShade = 0.1 * m
         End With
      Next m
   Next n
    Range("G1:S2").Font.Bold = True
    Columns("G:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

In case you wonder why all builtin Themes show dark colors for Light1/2 and light colors for Dark1/2 - It's probably a bug, or as MS would call it; it's a "feature" in Excel, and in Word too. In Powerpoint it's vice versa- more the way you would expect it to be.